# Why does Swipe-to-Delete crash under iOS 7?

Tags: ios, ios7

I started getting crash reports after a swipe-to-delete, and was able to recreate it. Then because I used Apple's iPhoneCoreDataRecipes example as a model, I tried the original sample code and that also crashes every time.

To recreate, just download and run the project at [CoreDataRecipes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes/Introduction/Intro.html). Then (1) click on, say, Macaroons to see the ingredients in the recipe, (2) swipe to delete an ingredient and (3) swipe on another ingredient. Crash.

My question is: Am I missing a bug in the example project code, or is this actually a bug in the OS?  And secondly, is there a workaround where one could recognize this scenario and defend against it, but still allow the swipe-to-delete? (For now, I just disable the swipe-to-delete by returning UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone from tableView:editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath: unless I'm already in Edit mode.)

In a list like this, the "Edit" button sends an setEditing:YES to the tableVC, which adds an "Add item" button in a new row (obviously to allow adding new items to the list), and the existing items get the red minus icon added to allow deletion. When finished, Done sends setEditing:NO, which removes the new row and the icons. That all works fine. (See Case 1 in debug output below).

If instead the user just wants to delete a single item, they can do so by swiping the item (and confirm by hitting Delete). To keep things consistent, the swipe also sends a setEditing:YES to the tableVC, and then the Delete button both sends a commitEditingStyle:delete message and a setEditing:NO message. The problem is that the system asks for the number of rows in the table in between those two messages, instead of after the setEditing:NO. Thus it remembers there being one more row than there actually is. Then if you do anything to the table (such as hitting Edit again, inserting the Add line again), it sees an inconsistent number of rows, and crashes.  See Case 2 in output below.

BTW, I think there's a second bug if you do the swipe to delete, but change your mind and hit Done (instead of clicking anywhere else than Delete). It calls setEditing:YES again recursively.  See Case 3 below in output

```
=============
>>CASE 1: Using Edit control to setEditing
2013-12-29 11:02:04.032 Recipes[10287:70b] Num Rows: 4 
2013-12-29 11:02:04.035 Recipes[10287:70b] Num Rows: 4 
-Hit Edit
2013-12-29 11:02:14.720 Recipes[10287:70b] setEditing: On
2013-12-29 11:02:14.725 Recipes[10287:70b] Inserting Add row 4
2013-12-29 11:02:14.726 Recipes[10287:70b] Num Rows: 4 +1
2013-12-29 11:02:14.727 Recipes[10287:70b] Providing Add Cell for row 4
-Hit EditControl ("-") then Delete
2013-12-29 11:02:21.806 Recipes[10287:70b] Deleting ingredient at row 2
2013-12-29 11:02:21.808 Recipes[10287:70b] Num Rows: 3 +1
-Hit Done
2013-12-29 11:02:28.032 Recipes[10287:70b] setEditing: Off
2013-12-29 11:02:28.036 Recipes[10287:70b] Deleting Add row 3
2013-12-29 11:02:28.036 Recipes[10287:70b] Num Rows: 3 

CASE 2: Using Swipe to Delete
2013-12-29 11:03:21.705 Recipes[10304:70b] Num Rows: 4 
2013-12-29 11:03:21.707 Recipes[10304:70b] Num Rows: 4 
-Swipe on row 2
2013-12-29 11:03:34.357 Recipes[10304:70b] setEditing: On
2013-12-29 11:03:34.358 Recipes[10304:70b] Inserting Add row 4
2013-12-29 11:03:34.359 Recipes[10304:70b] Num Rows: 4 +1
2013-12-29 11:03:34.359 Recipes[10304:70b] Providing Add Cell for row 4
-Hit Delete
2013-12-29 11:03:38.427 Recipes[10304:70b] Deleting ingredient at row 2
2013-12-29 11:03:38.431 Recipes[10304:70b] Num Rows: 3 +1
2013-12-29 11:03:38.432 Recipes[10304:70b] setEditing: Off
2013-12-29 11:03:38.434 Recipes[10304:70b] Deleting Add row 3         NOTE THAT IT DOES >>NOT<< CALL numberOfRows during this delete, but complains that current numberOfRows is wrong.
2013-12-30 23:54:26.349 Recipes[16694:70b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.80.1/UITableView.m:1366
2013-12-30 23:54:26.352 Recipes[16694:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 1.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (4) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (4), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01b48c94 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018c78b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01b48af8 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x005aa1ae -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   UIKit                               0x00ab3463 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 13402
    5   UIKit                               0x00ac313a -[UITableView endUpdatesWithContext:] + 51
    6   UIKit                               0x00ac3168 -[UITableView endUpdates] + 41
    7   Recipes                             0x00009a8c -[RecipeDetailViewController setEditing:animated:] + 908
    8   UIKit                               0x00cab0b5 -[UITableViewController tableView:willBeginEditingRowAtIndexPath:] + 49
    9   UIKit                               0x00abbb39 -[UITableView _sendWillBeginEditingForIndexPath:] + 73
    10  UIKit                               0x00ac772d -[UITableView _swipeCellAtPoint:] + 346
    11  UIKit                               0x00c44cd0 -[UITableViewCellScrollView gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:] + 354
    12  UIKit                               0x00d6d676 -[UIGestureRecognizer _shouldBegin] + 1309
    13  UIKit                               0x00d69f95 -[UIGestureRecognizer setState:] + 171
    14  UIKit                               0x00d9a9d7 -[UIPanGestureRecognizer touchesMoved:withEvent:] + 142
    15  UIKit                               0x00e4dd5a -[UIScrollViewPanGestureRecognizer touchesMoved:withEvent:] + 89
    16  UIKit                               0x00a1c148 -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] + 649
    17  UIKit                               0x00a1d2e1 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1021
    18  UIKit                               0x009eff32 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    19  UIKit                               0x009d9ec3 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11455
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x01ad1f5f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x01ad18eb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x01aee9be __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x01aee1e3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x01aedffb CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    25  GraphicsServices                    0x02f5a2c2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    26  GraphicsServices                    0x02f5a0e9 GSEventRun + 104
    27  UIKit                               0x009dcabb UIApplicationMain + 1225
    28  Recipes                             0x0000257d main + 125
    29  Recipes                             0x000024f5 start + 53
)




>>CASE 3: Using Swipe to Delete but then not deleting, with "Done"
2013-12-29 11:05:20.802 Recipes[10319:70b] Num Rows: 4 
2013-12-29 11:05:20.805 Recipes[10319:70b] Num Rows: 4 
-Swipe on row 2
2013-12-29 11:05:25.166 Recipes[10319:70b] setEditing: On
2013-12-29 11:05:25.167 Recipes[10319:70b] Inserting Add row 4
2013-12-29 11:05:25.168 Recipes[10319:70b] Num Rows: 4 +1
2013-12-29 11:05:25.168 Recipes[10319:70b] Providing Add Cell for row 4
-Hit Done
2013-12-29 11:05:27.685 Recipes[10319:70b] setEditing: Off
2013-12-29 11:05:27.686 Recipes[10319:70b] setEditing: Off
Breakpoint at beginning of setEditingAnimated shows:
#0  0x00008edb in -[RecipeDetailViewController setEditing:animated:] at /Users/hugh/Downloads/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes-2/Classes/RecipeDetailViewController.m:150
#1  0x00c90f1b in -[UITableViewController tableView:didEndEditingRowAtIndexPath:] ()
#2  0x00aadcbb in -[UITableView _sendDidEndEditingForIndexPath:] ()
#3  0x00ac4a1f in -[UITableView _endSwipeToDeleteRowDidDelete:] ()
#4  0x00abbdbb in -[UITableView _setEditing:animated:forced:] ()
#5  0x00abbf58 in -[UITableView setEditing:animated:] ()
#6  0x00c90982 in -[UITableViewController setEditing:animated:] ()
#7  0x00008f16 in -[RecipeDetailViewController setEditing:animated:] at /Users/hugh/Downloads/iPhoneCoreDataRecipes-2/Classes/RecipeDetailViewController.m:150
#8  0x00afc3ae in -[UIViewController(UINavigationControllerItem) _toggleEditing:] ()
#9  0x01853874 in -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] ()
#10 0x009d60c2 in -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] ()
#11 0x00caac9b in -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] ()

NOTE THE RECURSIVE CALL TO setEditing:animated:
AND CONTINUING LEADS TO THE CRASH:
2013-12-29 11:05:27.688 Recipes[10319:70b] Deleting Add row 4
2013-12-29 11:05:27.689 Recipes[10319:70b] Num Rows: 4 
2013-12-29 11:05:27.693 Recipes[10319:70b] Deleting Add row 4
2013-12-29 11:05:27.694 Recipes[10319:70b] Num Rows: 4 
2013-12-29 11:05:27.694 Recipes[10319:70b] *** Assertion failure in -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.23/UITableView.m:1076
2013-12-29 11:05:27.697 Recipes[10319:70b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete row 4 from section 1 which only contains 4 rows before the update'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x01abe5e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x018418b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x01abe448 +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 136
    3   Foundation                          0x005a3fee -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 116
    4   UIKit                               0x00aa3373 -[UITableView _endCellAnimationsWithContext:] + 3952
    5   UIKit                               0x00ab4caa -[UITableView endUpdatesWithContext:] + 51
    6   UIKit                               0x00ab4cd8 -[UITableView endUpdates] + 41
    7   Recipes                             0x000091fc -[RecipeDetailViewController setEditing:animated:] + 908
    8   UIKit                               0x00afc3ae -[UIViewController(UINavigationControllerItem) _toggleEditing:] + 73
    9   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01853874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    10  UIKit                               0x009d60c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    11  UIKit                               0x00caac9b -[UIBarButtonItem(UIInternal) _sendAction:withEvent:] + 139
    12  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x01853874 -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:withObject:] + 77
    13  UIKit                               0x009d60c2 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 108
    14  UIKit                               0x009d604e -[UIApplication sendAction:toTarget:fromSender:forEvent:] + 61
    15  UIKit                               0x00ace0c1 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 66
    16  UIKit                               0x00ace484 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 577
    17  UIKit                               0x00acd733 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 641
    18  UIKit                               0x00a1351d -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 852
    19  UIKit                               0x00a14184 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 1232
    20  UIKit                               0x009e7e86 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 242
    21  UIKit                               0x009d218f _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 11421
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x01a4783f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 15
    23  CoreFoundation                      0x01a471cb __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 235
    24  CoreFoundation                      0x01a6429e __CFRunLoopRun + 910
    25  CoreFoundation                      0x01a63ac3 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    26  CoreFoundation                      0x01a638db CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    27  GraphicsServices                    0x02eae9e2 GSEventRunModal + 192
    28  GraphicsServices                    0x02eae809 GSEventRun + 104
    29  UIKit                               0x009d4d3b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    30  Recipes                             0x00001ced main + 125
    31  Recipes                             0x00001c65 start + 53
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not yet sure if this is a bug of the CoreDataRecipes program or a bug in iOS 7,
but the following seems to work:

In `tableView:commitEditingStyle:editingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:`, in the swipe-to-delete case, we know 'self.editing' is NO at this point, so if you add a hack call to 'self.editing' after the deleteRows, the tableView seems to update its internal `numberOfRows`. Specifically, after:

```
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
```

add:

```
    if (!self.editing) self.editing = NO;
```

Secondly, in `setEditing:animated:`, check if the additional "Add Item" row actually exists before removing it. Specifically, replace:

```
    } else {
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:ingredientsInsertIndexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        overviewTextField.placeholder = @"";
    }
```

with:

```
    } else {
        if (ingredientsCount < [self.tableView numberOfRowsInSection:INGREDIENTS_SECTION]) {
            [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:ingredientsInsertIndexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        }
        overviewTextField.placeholder = @"";
    }
```

And this seems to solve both of your problems.

Comment: That definitely fixes the second problem (recursively calling the setEditing), but I'm still seeing the first, with or without the begin/endUpdates in commitEditingStyle. Did you make some other change as well?

Comment: @mackworth: Yes (I had tried different things, therefore I forgot about this one): In the delete case, I have explicitly set `self.editing = NO`.

Comment: That works, but in the true edit mode, it ends after the mode after a delete. If I change the `self.editing=NO` to : `if (!self.editing) self.editing = NO;` (a truly ugly statement), then it seems to work, as the second time we delete the add row seems to call numberOfRows properly.  I'm curious, I'm not seeing an animation problem that requires the begin/endUpdates, even in simulator slow motion. Did you do the self.editing = NO before or after the deleteRows?

Comment: @mackworth: Before the deleteRows. - And you are right, all this feels very hackish. Perhaps you should submit a Bugreport to Apple.

Comment: Adding it after seems to fix the animation.  I did submit, and was amused that I got a request back for the source code, so I zipped up their own code and sent it back to them. Haven't heard back.  Do you mind if I shorten the answer up some for anyone else looking at this?

Comment: @mackworth: Not at all, please do so!

Comment: Just FYI, for those explicitly calling setEditing:, apple recommends against calling it directly in commitEditingStyle:. From the docs: "You should not call setEditing:animated: within an implementation of this method. If for some reason you must, invoke it after a delay by using the performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: method."

Answer (score 1):

we saw that too .. looked like a bug: call reloadData after a modification as a workaround

Comment: Thanks. That indeed works, but loses all the editing animation for both the swipe and edit mode. I then tried having the Edit button point to a wrapper around setEditing:animated to remember that I'm in edit mode to avoid doing the reload in that scenario. That fixes that side, but it's not pretty code!